# How to reset the index after dropping column in data_frame

Tags: python, dataframe

After I delete a column in a dataframe, I need to reset the index.

Here is an example of the issue:

```
# importing the modules
import pandas as pd

# creating a DataFrame
orig = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(orig)

# displaying the original DataFrame
print("Original DataFrame :")
print(df)

# dropping the 0 column
df = df.drop(0, axis=1)
# displaying the altered DataFrame
print("DataFrame after removing the 0th column")
print(df)

# resetting the DataFrame index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# displaying the DataFrame with new index
print("Dataframe after resetting the index")
print(df)`
```

This is the output:
Original DataFrame :

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

DataFrame after removing the 0th column

```
   1  2
0  2  3
1  5  6
2  8  9
```

Dataframe after resetting the index

```
   1  2
0  2  3
1  5  6
2  8  9
```

I was expecting the first column index to be 0 instead of 1.  And the 2nd column index to be 1 instead of 2.

Comment: You could directly change `df.columns`. For example, if you want to have 0, 1 indices you could do: `df.columns = range(df.columns.size)` instead of `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`. Then it depends on which column names you want, but that's a way you can approach the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using `transpose` or `T` and `reset_index`:

```
df.T.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True).T
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  2  3
1  5  6
2  8  9
```

---

Here's another way using the "walrus operator" in python 3.8+ and `set_axis`:

```
(dfi:=df.drop(0, axis=1)).set_axis(range(dfi.shape[1]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  2  3
1  5  6
2  8  9
```